# Image in navigation bar won't scale down in size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to set an image in my navigation bar's title view but no matter the content mode I use the image is huge and exceeds the bounds of the navigation bar. I am setting the image to the bar with this (in viewDidLoad):

```
    let banner = UIImage(named: "banner.png")
    let bannerView = UIImageView(image:banner)
    bannerView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.navigationItem.titleView = bannerView
```

Using ScaleAspectFill has similar results. Is there a way to scale down the size of the image? I really would love to avoid image editors.

Comment: try to set the frame for imageview

Answer (score 3):

After a long search through many open tickets for this issue I tried modifying the constraints and it works. I hope it helps

```
let banner = UIImage(named: "banner.png")
let bannerView = UIImageView(image:banner)
bannerView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = bannerView
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.navigationItem.titleView!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),self.navigationItem.titleView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))    
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit    
imageView.image =  UIImage(named: "logo")
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Here you find some web reference http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-navigation-bar-ios8-swift

Also you can meet some problems with image scaling i.e. for iPad2 - then check my question on SO [Resizing image for icons for iPad2 - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673330/resizing-image-for-icons-for-ipad2-swift)